# Tem algum comando do tipo "parse" para jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Recebo uma string tipo : R$10,00, queria mudar para 10.00 para poder fazer calculo, tentei o códio abaixo, mas não deu certo.

```
   for (let i=0; i<numColunas; i++){
     valor = (colunas[i].textContent).parse("R$", "");
     alert(valor);    
  }
```

Comment: Dá pra você utilizar o `String.replace`, ex: `(colunas[i].textContent).replace('R$', '').replace(',', '.')`. Veja mais em [MDN - String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Excelente amigo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use expressão regular pra remover tudo que não for números e `virgula`

```
var teste = 'R$10,00';
teste = teste.replace(/[^0-9\,]/g, '');
```

Troque `vírgula` por `ponto` e transforme o valor para float, assim poderá fazer cálculos com ele

```
teste = teste.replace(',', '.');
teste = parseFloat(teste);
```

Answer (score 0):

A função abaixo é compacta e resolve este problema:

```
function floatvalue($val){
            $val = str_replace(",",".",$val);
            $val = preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', $val);
            return floatval($val);
}

$string = "12,34";
$number = floatvalue($string);

$r = 40 + 7.5 + $number;

echo $r;
```

[Publicação original em inglês - crédito pela solução a "user3690160"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float/44110263#44110263)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o *replace* com uma *regex* que que pega apenas os números e vírgula.

> É necessário também excluir todos os pontos do número antes de
>   substituir a vírgula, porque caso o número tenha separador de milhar,
>   irá dar problema (ex. `R$10.000,00` ficará `10.000.00`).

```
valor = parseFloat(("R$10.000,55").replace(/[^\d,]/g, "").replace(',','.'));
```

No seu caso, ficaria:

```
valor = parseFloat((colunas[i].textContent).replace(/[^\d,]/g, "").replace(',','.'));
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
valor = parseFloat(("R$10.000,55").replace(/[^\d,]/g, "").replace(',','.'));
console.log((valor+10.99).toFixed(2));
```